# Is it possible to generate artifacts without publishing with Semantic-release?

Tags: semantic-release

I'm currently using semantic-release for versioning of my react library.
https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release

Question: 
Is it possible to generate the artifacts without publishing it?

For example, in my use case I would like to generate:
- Version Release Number (@semantic-release/commit-analyzer)
- tar file that will be publish to npm (@semantic-release/npm)
- change log (@semantic-release/release-notes-generator)

If you run the dry run option, it will print the version release number and the change log to console, but I want to store it to a file.  One workaround is I could pipe the results and then parse, but it'll be nice if it can pass the plugin could put the data in a file during the dry run.

The dry run won't run the publish stage which is where the files get tar'ed up.

Any Advice appreciated,
Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`npmPublish` option](https://github.com/semantic-release/npm#options) of the `@semantic-release/npm` plugin. This will generate the tar file for the npm package but it won't publish it to the npm registry.

Answer (score 1):

// In your package.json file add the following property which ensures that npm will not publish

```
"private": "true"
```

// In your github action's workflow/release.yml file use the following to store your tar file

```
- run: | 
      mkdir -p ~/new/artifact
      echo ${{contents_of_your_file}} > ~/new/artifact/yourtarfile

  - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: artifactname
      path: '~/new/**/*'

  - name: download
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
    with:
      name: artifactname
      path: '~/new/**/*'
```